# Запрос SQL на создание трёх таблиц, проблема со связями

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Имеется задание для создания маленькой БД. Нужно её только создать согласно условиям и требованиям. Я создал, но, как мне кажется, не все требования выполняются касаемо должности. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если создал таблицы неверно, то как можно поправить запросы?
Задание:
В базе данных обязательно должна быть сохранена следующая информация о сотрудниках:

1. ФИО – Фамилия Имя Отчество сотрудника;
2. Дата рождения – дата рождения сотрудника;
3. Должность – занимаемая должность сотрудника в этой организации;
4. Подразделение – отдел, в котором работает сотрудник.

В требованиях предметной области указано, что сотрудник числится только в одном подразделении, в каждом подразделении работает много со-трудников, при этом согласно штатному расписанию в разных подразделениях могут работать сотрудники с одинаковым названием должности. Какие таблицы и с какой структурой Вы создадите для хранения данной информации? Напишите инструкции создания таблиц.

Мой запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE positions
(
    id_position SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    position_name CHARACTER VARYING(100) NOT NULL
);
 
CREATE TABLE divisions
(
    id_division SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    division_name CHARACTER VARYING(100) NOT NULL
);
 
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    id_employee SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL, 
    employee_name CHARACTER VARYING(100) NOT NULL,
    position_id INTEGER REFERENCES positions (id_position),
    division_id INTEGER REFERENCES divisions (id_division)
);
```

Comment: да вроде все отлично, точно соответствует требованиям

Comment: Если ограничиться только заданием - созданная схема соответствует ему. Если же вспомнить о реалиях и существовании штатного расписания, то схема неверна.

Comment: @Akina да, вот это и вызвало у меня сомнения. Вот не уверен, как в реалиях можно это сделать.

Comment: При существовании штатного расписания соотношение division-position является самостоятельной сущностью "штатная единица", которая должна храниться в отдельной таблице (и иметь дополнительные атрибуты, ибо в подразделении может быть несколько штатных единиц с одинаковой должностью) и связываться с таблицей работников как 1:(0-1).